# ASP.NET MVC update multiple rows Postgresql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

I'm trying to update multiple rows in one view to Postgresql.
Code below is updating only the first row, any solutions?

```
private readonly AppDbContext appDbContext;

public EmployeeRepository(AppDbContext db)
{
    db = appDbContext;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    model = db.Contacts.ToList();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Contact> list)
{ 
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            var c = db.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactID.Equals(i.ContactID)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (c != null)
            {
                c.ContactPerson = i.ContactPerson;
                c.Contactno = i.Contactno;
                c.EmailID = i.EmailID;
            }
        }

        dc.SaveChanges();

        return View(list);
}
```

View

```
@model List<UpdateMultiRecord.Contact>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>               
            <th>Contact Person</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>Email ID</th>
        </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>               
            <td> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ContactID)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].ContactPerson)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Contactno)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].EmailID)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
  
   }
   @section Scripts{
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I would like to edit many rows (like 100) in one view and save data to postgresql, maybe someone have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the context in the for loop?

Comment: Can you give me example how update context in the for loop?